# Cast to ObjectId failed for value ... at path "_id" for model but I am not doing any query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an express route that gets call with axios from the frontend. The thing is, not matter what I put into the route I always get the same error:

**"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "getTodosMisProductos" at path "_id" for model "local""**

I'm not doing any query to mongoose in that route but in any other route where I make a query everything works fine.

I've checked the middleware but there is not any query to mongoose

**getTodosMisProductos**

```
router.get("/getTodosMisProductos", auth, async (req, res) => {
  /*
  try {
    const data = await Local.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).populate("products.producto");
    console.log(data);

    if (!data) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: "No se encontro el local" }] });
    }

    return res.status(200).json(data.products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(req.user.id);
    console.error("error en llamado");
    return res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
  */
  console.log("algo");
  return res.status(200).json({ msg: "success" });
});
```

the code commented is the code I need to use, I changed it for testing purposes but even with that simple new code I get the same error.

**auth middleware**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  // Get token from header
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  // Check if not token
  if (!token) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ msg: "No tienes autorización para hacer esto" });
  }

  // Verify token
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, require("../config/keys").jwtSecret);

    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: "El token es inválido" });
  }
};
```

**action from where the route gets called**

```
export const getAllProductos = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    console.log("Esto se llama");
    const res = await axios.get("/api/local/getTodosMisProductos/");

    dispatch({
      type: SET_PRODUCTS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
    }
  }
};
```

The response status is always 500 (Internal Server Error)

**EDIT**

```
//@route   GET api/local/:id
//@desc    obtener local por id
//@access  private
router.get("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const local = await Local.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!local) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: "No se encontro el local" }] });
    }

    return res.status(200).json(local);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have another route that looks like this? `/api/local/:id`

Comment: Yes. I'll add it in the question so you can check it.

Comment: That's exactly where the error occurs, `/api/local/getTodosMisProductos/` gets matched by `/api/local/:id` and you get `req.params.id` as getTodosMisProductos

Comment: Ok that was the problem. Thank you! but I have other routes with that same format that didnt bring any error. e.g /api/local/addProducto

Comment: The order in which you declare the route affects the matching priority. It's possible that `/api/local/addProducto` gets declared before `/api/local/:id`

Answer (score 0):

You have another route that also match `/api/local/getTodosMisProductos/`

Apparently it got matched with `/api/local/:id`,

where you get `req.params.id = "getTodosMisProductos"` and got passed down to `await Local.findById(req.params.id)`

And mongoose can't convert `"getTodosMisProductos"` to `ObjectId`, hence the error.

The order in which you declare the route affects the matching priority.

The order is first comes first serves, so make sure you declare `/api/local/addProducto` or any other routes that starts with `/api/local/` *before* declaring `/api/local/:id`